# Does a charged isotope have a different half life than the neutral counterpart?

Tags: isotopes, half-life

Let's say you have a radioactive isotope of an element with relatively short half-life (e.g. <0.5s).

If you add or remove electrons from the atom so that is has a positive or negative charge, is there any effect on the half-life of the isotope, or is that behavior restricted to the nucleus itself?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/167168/do-chemical-bonds-impact-half-life-of-elements/167170#167170 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/713918/can-a-beryllium-7-nuclei-be-stable-if-it-has-lost-its-electrons/713923#713923 have relevance

Comment: Another relevant question is ["Isotope that decays when ionized"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691553/145491).