# What is the half-life of isotopes that decay via electron capture, if they are stripped of their electrons?

Tags: radioactivity, half-life, proton-decay

If an isotope that undergoes decay via electron capture, like 7Be, loses ONE electron, how will its radioactive half life change? What about 2 electrons? And so on and so forth for heavier elements? How do you calculate the change in half lives depending on the number of electrons lost? Do all electrons lost effectively translate to a "stable" isotope?

Comment: I am not sure that I will be responding to what you are asking, but I will try. The half-life is defined as a quantity proportional to the decay rate of a reaction, whose initial state is particle $X$ and whose final state is particles $Y$ and $Z$ for example. By calculating the scattering amplitude and from there the decay rate, one can easily specify the half-life for any process.

Comment: @schris38 sorry, I should have been more clear. I meant to ask, if an isotope that undergoes decay via electron capture, like 7Be, loses ONE electron, how will its radioactive half life change? What about 2 electrons? And so on and so forth for heavier elements

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. This latest comment of yours would make for a much more interesting and concise question than the many questions you have currently asked

Comment: @rfl sorry! I just changed the questions and the description. I was a little flustered and short for time on a code change, so wasn't very articulate at first. Now it seems I have quite a bit of time to explore this.

Comment: [Closely related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691553/44126). Beryllium-7 is unstable on Earth, but bare Be-7 is a stable component of the cosmic ray spectrum. To good approximation, only $s$-wave electrons capture; you can get an idea of relative capture probabilities from the relative rates of K-, L-, M-shell (and higher) x-rays.

Comment: The rate of decay is proportional to the squared norm of the matrix element <in|V|out> where V describes the nuclear interactions that yields the decay. These nuclear interactions are of very short range, this means that the matrix element will be proportional to the integral of the atomic wavefunction where you put one electron at the origin (i.e. inside the nucleus, with the nucleus approximated to be a single point at the origin). This means that the amplitude will depend on the number of electrons in s-orbitals.

Comment: I rather suspect that the half-life of an ion vs. that of the electrically neutral atom are the same.   Capturing an electron in the nucleus is completely different (cross-section, etc) from simply refilling the electron shells either from local free electrons or by bonding into a molecule.